# HTML: How to add an image using CSS as linked style sheet

Tags: html, css

Here's my code.  I'm trying to add an image called lg.png into the HTML and be able to edit the length/width in the css file.  The lg.png is located in the same folder as the index.html and styles.css

Tried looking online for this answer but can't seem to get any luck.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

```
<head>
    <title>yournetid</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>   
</head>
<img id="my_image" src="lg.png" alt="image error"/>

        &nbsp;
<body>
    <p>
        Here's some awesome pictures!
    </p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
```

}

`img#lg background:url(lg.png); 
width:200px; 
height:100px;`

Comment: background image of image? take a `div` instead of the image and do that.

Comment: Is it a valid vanilla CSS? You can't nest styles (`img#lg` is inside `body`) BTW `img#lg` won't match your image (because it has not `lg` id).

Comment: You need to fix the opening body tag and I see no link in the HTML file to the CSS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use CSS selector `img#lg` which makes no sense. You are telling CSS to look for an image with id of 'lg' but you did not set any id to your image.

Also, setting the `background-image:ur(lg.png)` is not the same as `<img src='lg.png'>`.

To fix it:

1. Add id to your image
2. Target the id in your CSS.

Change your HTML:

```
 <img id="my_image" src="lg.png" alt="image error">
```

CSS:

```
#my_image {width:200px; height:100px; }
```

If you wanted to change CSS properties of ALL images, you'd use the following:

```
img {width:200px; height:100px; }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm still getting a couple errors, as it's not displaying the image.

Error: "In XHTML 1.0 Strict the tag <html> cannot contain tag <img>

Comment: @user3245569 where is the image located? is it in the same folder of the HTML or a subfolder?

Comment: It's in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: I also updated the original post with what I'm currently working with.

Comment: @user3245569 why are you using strict xhtml? and not simply <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: I was able to tinker with things and get it to work with 0 errors using your help.  I removed the strict aspect and I changed a few things around to get it to look well.

Honestly, I was using strict because my professor gave it to me to work with it that way.  I know it wasn't necessarily needed, but I left it for the sake of example.

Thank you very much for your help.  I should be able to get the rest of this done fairly easily

Comment: tell your professor it's 2014 :) he may just want to force you to use strict markup for educational purposes...

Answer (score 4):

Use a `div` and set the `background` property:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="my_image"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.my_image
{
    background:URL('path/to/img.png');
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Made some changes to what I'm currently working with, still stumped on where to go in the right direction since the image still isn't showing up